# Location in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to make an application in Windows 8 that can locate the user's location. for this I have the following class

```
public sealed partial class Cercano : CentrosCo.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    Geolocator geo = null;
    public Cercano()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async void button1_Click(
        object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (geo == null)
        {
            geo = new Geolocator();
        }

        IGeoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
        textLatitude.Text = "Latitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
        textLongitude.Text = "Longitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
        textAccuracy.Text = "Accuracy: " + pos.Coordinate.Accuracy.ToString();
    }
```

In IGeoposition get the error:

> Windows.Devices.Geolocation.IGeoposition is inaccesible due to its potection level,

Select location already in the manifesto ...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. This is an English only Q&A site, so it'd be nice if you could rewrite this in English. =)

Comment: Buenos dias amigo! No hablamos Espanol aqui. Puedes escribir en Ingles?

Comment: Provided a Google translated version. Original question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13161016/1).

Comment: You cannot make a `IGeoposition` variable because its an interface class.  We would need to know what `GetGeopositionAsync()` actually returns to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async return type of the [Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx) is [*Geoposition*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geoposition.aspx), not *IGeoposition*.

Try this:

```
Geoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
```